# Unable to add custom domain to github page

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-pages, amazon-route53, custom-domain

I am absolutely new to GitHub so this may come out as a silly question. I am trying to host my website using GitHub pages. The website got hosted properly, but when I added the custom domain, it stopped working and now I am getting a blank page. What I have done is, have created a subdomain in my AWS-hosted zones (subdomain.example.com) and pointed it to https://my_org.github.io/my_repo/

Then I added subdomain.example.com in github page custom domain and CNAME file in the repository.

The error I am getting is

> DNS check unsuccessful
> subdomain.example.com is improperly configured Domain's DNS record
> could not be retrieved. For more information, see documentation
> (InvalidDNSError).

I am not sure what I am missing exactly. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Have you created a CNAME record on AWS Route53?

Comment: @VladHolubiev Yes

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to verify your domain name through a TXT record:

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/verifying-your-custom-domain-for-github-pages